# sum of two random variables with geometric distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

**hello**.
i've got 3 random variables, $X$, $Y$ with $GEO$ ~ $(p)$ for both , and $X+Y = Z$.

i need to calculate $P(X | Z=k)$.

so i started with: $P(X|Z=k)=P(X|X+Y=k)=P(x=j|X+Y=k)= \dfrac{P(X=j,X+Y=k)}{(1-p)^kp}$

but, how do i calculate this: $P(X=j,X+Y=k)$ ?
pls guide me.

edit: nothing is mention about if X and y are independent or not, in the question.

Comment: More information is needed. Are $X$ and $Y$ independent? You could also have $X=Y$. Add that info to your question (not in a comment).

Answer (score 1):

If $X, Y$ are *independent* and the geometric distribution is counting *trials until success* then:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(X=j, X+Y=k) & = \mathsf P(X=j)\;\mathsf P(Y=k-j)
\\ & = (1-p)^{j-1}p\cdot (1-p)^{k-j-1}p
\\ & = (1-p)^{k-2}p^2
\end{align}$$

---

If $X, Y$ are *independent* and the geometric distribution is counting *failures before success* then:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(X=j, X+Y=k) & = \mathsf P(X=j)\;\mathsf P(Y=k-j)
\\ & = (1-p)^{j}p\cdot (1-p)^{k-j}p
\\ & = (1-p)^{k}p^2
\end{align}$$

---

If $X,Y$ are not independent then you need more information about their joint probability.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(X=j, X+Y=k) & = \mathsf P(X=j\cap Y=k-j)
\\ & = ?
\end{align}$$

---

PS: Rethink the denominator of your Bayesian:
 $$\mathsf P(X+Y=k) = \sum_{j=0}^k \mathsf P(X=j, y=k-j)$$

Answer (score 0):

> but, how do i calculate this: $P(X=j,X+Y=k)$ ?

First, you note that $P(X=j,X+Y=k)=P(X=j,Y=k-j)$. Second, you realize that **you forgot to mention the hypothesis that $X$ and $Y$ are independent**. Third, you use this hypothesis to get $P(X=j,Y=k-j)=P(X=j)P(Y=k-j)$. Fourth, you identify $P(X=j)$ and $P(Y=k-j)$. Last you multiply them and divide the result by $P(X+Y=k)$ to get $P(X=j\mid Z=k)$. *Et voilà!*